# How to identify the presence of scroll in a web page. Also get the co ordinates of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I have web page where I need to get the scroll co-ordinates of the page dynamically. Suppose if a page has 2 scrolls, I should get 2 scroll co-ordinates. So, it should be dynamic depending on the page.

```
var coordObj = []; 
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); 
for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) { 
     var hasHorizontalScrollbar = divs[i].scrollWidth > divs[i].clientWidth; 
     var hasVerticalScrollbar = divs[i].scrollHeight > divs[i].clientHeight; 
     if(hasVerticalScrollbar || hasHorizontalScrollbar) {
          var getCoords=divs[i].getBoundingClientRect(); 
          coordObj.push(getCoords);
     }
}
return coordObj;
```

Answer (score 1):

Three ways to do this in vanilla HTML/JS.

First, you can use the `onscroll` HTML attribute:

```html
<div id="outer" onscroll="handleScroll(this);">
    Content
    <div id="inner" onscroll="handleScroll(this);">
       Inner Content
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function handleScroll(y) {
        console.log(y.scrollTop);
    }
</script>
```

Second, you can add a Javascript event listener:

```html
<div id="outer">
    Content
    <div id="inner">
      Inner Content
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var outer = document.getElementById("outer");
    outer.addEventListener("scroll", () => console.log(outer.scrollTop));
</script>
```

Third, you can use the `onscroll` JS method:

```html
<div id="outer">
    Content
    <div id="inner">
      Inner Content
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    let outer = document.getElementById("outer");
    outer.onscroll = () => console.log(outer.scrollTop);
</script>
```

Use `elem.scrollLeft` for X coordinate, and `elem.scrollTop` for Y coordinate.